# Apache error 500 server not working/not workin different method

Tags: php

In short, the problem is that everything seems to be set up correctly. Script with auto-installation. I use VDS from FirstVDS.

But I can't understand why the error is happening.

In the logs:
`PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/www-root/data:.) in /var/www/www-root/data/www/localhost.fvds.ru/core/vendor/vonage/nexmo-bridge/src/Autoloader.php on line 69, referer: https://localhost.fvds.ru/admin/dashboard`

According to the idea, it refers to the fact that the file_exists() function is trying to access the file autoload.php and because of the limitation of open_basedir in PHP configs.

Well, I decided to do this in the configs
`open_basedir = /var/www/www-root/data:/var/www/www-root/data/www/denshame.fvds.ru/core`

Rebooted the Apache server. And nothing has changed. As this error appeared in the logs, it appears further.

Here is the code Autoloader.php where 69 error lines appear.

```
/**
     * @throws RuntimeException
     */
    private static function getClassLoader() : ClassLoader
    {
        if (file_exists(getenv('COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR') . '/autoload.php')) {
            return include getenv('COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR') . '/autoload.php';
        }

        if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../../../autoload.php')) {
            return include __DIR__ . '/../../../autoload.php';
        }

        if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php')) {
            return include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
        }

        throw new RuntimeException('Cannot detect composer autoload. Please run composer install');
    }
```

[image: Screenshot of network tab with 500 response]
[image: Screenshot of 500 server error]

Well, I decided to do this in the configs
`open_basedir = /var/www/www-root/data:/var/www/www-root/data/www/denshame.fvds.ru/core`

Rebooted the Apache server. And nothing has changed. As this error appeared in the logs, it appears further.

Comment: _"And nothing has changed."_ - and why should it; `/autoload.php` isn't in either of those folders you specified there. Are you not aware, that a file system path that begins with a slash, refers to the _root_ of the file system? `file_exists(getenv('COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR') . '/autoload.php')` - so apparently `getenv('COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR')` must have returned only an empty string here.